# origin of the phrase "up against"?

Tags: phrases

The phrase " be up against something(someone)" means to confront someone, or to have deal with something. For example:

> He is going to be up against them.

But where does the phrase come from, and what is the meaning of the word "up" there?

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic expression is from the late 19th century. It is probably derived from the more common idiomatic expression ***[up against the wall:](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/19/messages/1140.html)***

***[Be up against something/somebody:](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+up+against)***

> if you are up against a situation, a person, or a group of people, they make it very difficult for you to achieve what you want to achieve
>
> - *When I saw how deeply the racist views were held I began to understand what we were up against. The Welsh rugby team **will really be up against it** (= have a lot of problems) when they take on France next week.*

(Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed.)

***[Up against it](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/up--against--it)***
(adjective phrase)

> In a difficult situation; in serious trouble :
>
> - When they saw the gap they knew they were really up against it ***(1896+)***

(The Dictionary of American Slang)

Comment: What evidence is there for it deriving from 'up against the wall'?

Comment: What @Spagirl said. I'd say that being up against something is much older than the expression *up against the wall*. (But I don't have any evidence of that, other than my memory, according to which *up against the wall* became widely known in the 60s.)

Comment: Perhaps it comes from the idea of having to 'stand up and fight'.